# Qt Available Serial Ports Memory Leak

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am using Qt 5.5 and VS2013 and I'm trying to get all the available serial ports inside a class constructor as:

```
QList<QSerialPortInfo> ports = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
```

I get all the ports connected (COM1, COM2, etc.). However, when the constructor finishes I get this Debug Assertion error:

```
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

Comment: When what constructor finishes? Where is the rest of your code? Since you posted one line only - if you put that line in a `main` body, with preceding `QCoreApplication app(argc, argv)` and nothing else - can you reproduce it? This really needs a test case to reproduce, otherwise you're likely facing ill effects of other code of yours.